# Jenkins build fail with Android Google API

Tags: android, ant, build, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have an Android project with target Google API level 15, which I can successfully build locally on my machine with Ant. The issue is, however that when I try to build it on my jenkins server I get the following exception:

```
build.xml:539: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.loadPlatforms(SdkManager.java:467)
    at com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.reloadSdk(SdkManager.java:151)
    at com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager(SdkManager.java:132)
    at com.android.ant.GetTargetTask.execute(GetTargetTask.java:121)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1360)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1329)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1212)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

I have installed Google API level 15 @ my Jenkins server. Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - my jenkins user wasn't given the required permissions on the `sdk` directory...